# Xamarin Forms with CRM365 API

Tags: c#, api, xamarin.forms, dynamics-crm

I am trying to develop a Xamarin forms application to talk to CRM365 on premise API. I tried with c# console app, and it is working perfectly, but the same code on Xamarin forms brings the below errors:

---

*Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   NU1202  Package MSCRMSolutions.System.ServiceModel 4.6.1055.1 is not compatible with monoandroid12.0 (MonoAndroid,Version=v12.0). Package MSCRMSolutions.System.ServiceModel 4.6.1055.1 supports:

- net40 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0)
- net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)  App11.Android   C:\Users***\source\repos\App11\App11\App11.Android\App11.Android.csproj    1*

---

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   NU1202  Package MSCRMSolutions.System.ServiceModel 4.6.1055.1 is not compatible with netstandard1.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.0). Package MSCRMSolutions.System.ServiceModel 4.6.1055.1 supports:

- net40 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0)
- net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)  App11   C:\Users***\source\repos\App11\App11\App11\App11.csproj

---

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   NU1202  Package Microsoft.CrmSdk.XrmTooling.CoreAssembly 9.1.1.1 is not compatible with netstandard1.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.CrmSdk.XrmTooling.CoreAssembly 9.1.1.1 supports: net462 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2)    App11   C:\Users***\source\repos\App11\App11\App11\App11.csproj

I have been searching for hours, without success. Any ideas? Thank you...

Comment: Those packages (which have not been updated in three years) are not compatible with the .NET versions used in Xamarin.  Contact the vendor to see if they intend to update their libraries

Comment: Thanks Jason for your reply. Do you mean crmsdk. Xrm. Tooling... Nuget? It is from Microsoft and it should be the latest version.?

Comment: I only checked the ServiceModel nuget.  I assume the others are similar

Comment: And that one does not appear to be an official MS release.  There is not even a valid link to the project site

Comment: XrmTooling ONLY supports 4.6.2, which is **6 years old**.  I don’t know much about CRM, but that seems like an odd decision for an official MS release

Comment: For the Xrm tooling, actually VS intellsense suggested this nuget, but, can you recommend a way to connect to Dynamics365 Api from. Xamarin? Using httpclient maybe?

Comment: My examination matches Jason's. It looks like `Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreAssemblies` nuget is Windows-only, and has never been migrated from the windows-specific ".Net Framework" to any of the potentially cross-platform .Net versions (Core, Standard, .Net 6).  At [Dynamics 365 REST APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/dynamics365/) I see links to using Postman with their Web API. Maybe start there. So, yes, httpclient.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. I find it strange though, that all (VS + Nuget + Xamarin) are Microsoft products and still have compatibility issues. Maybe Microsoft are urging people to use their Android Application (Dynamics365) instead of developing their own. :). Regards

Comment: @AbedElHameedJaber there is now a nuget package that should be compatible https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client/ but you can always use http calls as suggested above.

Comment: Hello, I tried the nuget package mentioned above (PowerPlatform) but still the same problem!

Comment: Did you try to use the http calls?

Comment: Yes, the http call are working without a problem, but the capabilities the SDK offers is way much better than the http calls. Please check this article: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/using-web-api-function-in-crm-2016-part-1/